# jQuery to place a div at a particular position after calculating window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window

I want to place a div based on calculation of window height using jQuery.
Here's my code snippet:

```
var winHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Now I get the height of the window.
I want to place a div at the bottom of window based on the height.
This is because the height varies but irrespective of the height, this DIV should be placed at the bottom by giving some styles to this DIV.

Note : I am adding the div via jQuery dynamically. So I need to calculate the height of the page and display it. Because the content/height of the page will vary. Thats why I need to add the css style based on window height via jQuery

Please Help.

Thanks,

Comment: `$('div').css('top', $(window).height() - $('div').height())`, or simpler, `bottom : 0px`

Comment: You can do this in CSS alone, `position: fixed; bottom: 0` on the div, then `margin-bottom` on the container which matches the height of the fixed div to stop any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for that. I would suggest using CSS `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`:

```css
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">I'm always at the bottom</div>
```